# ConEmu attempts to open and crashes immediately

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, conemu

I've been using ConEmu x64 on my home computer with Git Bash, and it works well for me.

I recently started a new job and I haven't been able to get them to work together on my new machine.
At first ConEmu would run just fine but wouldn't run git bash, now after a few uninstalls when I try to launch conemu it tries to open and crashes immediately.

Git Bash works on it's own, although it's opening inside MinGW which is different than how it works on my home machine.
I don't know much about the distinction between mingw and git bash but I know mingw comes with git bash on windows.

I'm running Windows 10 on both computers and I've set the corresponding environment variables to be exactly the same using Rapid EE.

How can I launch a bash session within the ConEmu windows, without crash?

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/BadIssue.html

Comment: Okaaaaay...... Windows OS, version 10, ConEmu x64 and I've tried multiple different versions on my work computer, the one I have running on my home computer is 151217; I went back and downloaded that on the work machine and it crashes. I've tried the current stable and alpha versions (using the installer in every case.) I can't take a screenshot because the window opens and closes so quickly, and I don't know how to make debug logs (apologies, I'm still a new-ish developer.) It looks like ConEmu is trying to launch Git Bash when it crashes. I have Git 2.7

Answer (score 3):

Finally fixed my issue - I uninstalled git bash and then the conemu window would stay open. I checked the Settings tab and the terminal was trying to open git bash still, and the path to the file was no longer valid. So after clearing out all the pre-defined tasks, I was able to re-install ConEmu an Git Bash and set the correct path to the git bash .exe. Works just fine now. I definitely appreciate conemu, as a Windows user in a Linux environment it's a super useful tool.

Comment: My issue was also something with git so uninstalling git stopped the crashing. Then I removed git from startup tasks and now it works even after reinstalling git

Answer (score 0):

I usually:

- unzip https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.7.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.7.2-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere I want,
- add the folder to the PATH, and
- I am able to call `<path\to\git\bin\bash.exe>` in a ConEmu session without any issue.

Comment: thanks Von! However, the problem is that right now I can't even get ConEmu to launch and stay open; the window opens for just about 1 second and then crashes/disappears. On my home computer I was able to configure conemu to open git bash just as you said. Unfortunately I don't know how to diagnose what's happening with the application crashing.

Comment: @BlakeSchwartz Then try this: zip the ConEmu installation folder, then uninstall ConEmu. Once uninstalled, unzip the ConEmu archive, and try launching `ConEmu64.exe`. See if that stays open. I use the `ConEmuPack.151208` without any issue.

Comment: Thanks Von, I'll try that. I haven't tried installing via zip file yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see "Crash message", than it's improperly to say that ConEmu crashes. If your shell terminates immediately and *properly*, than ConEmu closes its window by default, and that is normal and expected behavior.

So your question must be rephrased like "Why my bash instance terminates immediately after start". The question does not relate to ConEmu itself.

However, reading [ConEmu docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html) would give you much interesting notes. Especially:

- `ConEmu -detached`
- `ConEmu -basic`
- `ConEmu -log`
- `ConEmu -?` at last!

Comment: Thank you sir, that does look like promising info for my case. I suspected that my issue could be caused by the windows shell(?) or whatever process launches ConEmu itself, but I am completely ignorant of how that works (I assume ConEmu runs inside a Windows command line utility like cmd?) Where would one run the commands listed in your docs, if the conemu window won't stay open? Within the Windows CLI, or Git BAsh? Thanks again.

Comment: `Win+R` https://conemu.github.io/en/Delusions.html  https://conemu.github.io/en/ProcessMonitor.html

Comment: Still no luck... Like I said, my lack of debugging knowledge/experience seems to be the main problem. Although now I'm pretty convinced it's actually an issue with git bash more so than conemu - if I uninstall both, then re-install conemu without git, I can open conemu and it just opens a 'cmd.exe' tab. What's odd is that if I open the settings->tasks menu, it has git and putty listed there, despite git having been removed. Once I re-install git though the launch/crash problem starts again. It looks like git bash's path isn't getting picked up properly.

Comment: Really a bummer because using putty in a linux environment is very much less than ideal.